# How can I make the top and bottom elements of my view controller stay in place, while the middle has elements to vertically scroll through?

Tags: xcode, swift3

I'm working in Swift 3 and XCode 8.

I tried to find the answer to this question, but maybe I don't know how to ask it properly. I'm trying to have a title bar at the top of a view controller and have a back and next button at the bottom of the view. The content in between is longer than the space that exists, so I would like the user to be able to scroll the middle, but keep the top and bottom elements anchored in place.

I've tried to use a container with another view controller that is larger than the container to make this happen, but it just resizes the child view controller.

If I'm not explaining something properly, please let me know and I will try to give more information about what I've missed.

Comment: Have you tried using a scroll view for the middle content?

Comment: @RyanH. Thanks for the reply. The scroll view looks like what I want. Would you be able to give me a few pointers on how to implement it? It doesn't seem to work like a container view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions about your Views:

- Navigation Bar for your title
- Toolbar to hold your Back and Next buttons

Try the following:

1. Place a Navigation Bar as seen below. Do not set any constraints.
2. Place a Toolbar as seen below. Again, do not set any constraints.
3. Place a Scroll View in the centre of your View Controller and expand it so that the top and bottom are aligned with the navigation bar and toolbar respectively. Again, do not set any constraints.
4. Highlight all of the Views in the View Controller and place them in a Stack View.
5. Pin the Stack View to the Superview. These are the only constraints that are set in the example below.

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks! I've been able to find more documentation, I just didn't know the terminology I was searching for.